# Parsing a flat text file

Tags: delphi

I am developing an application and I have to upload data from CSV files into a DB tables. Problem is, I don’t have CSV files but I have flat text files to be converted into CSV. 
An additional problem is, as the application is used by  several customers who have different systems, I have different flat text files with different layouts.

What I want to achieve is to create an application that loads “rules” from a special file; these rules will be processed with the flat text file in order generate the CSV file. The application that converts from flat file to CSV would be the same, just the set of rules would be different.

How can I achieve this? What is the best practice you recommend?

Comment: Quite how complex your rules language needs to be depends on how complex and varied your input files are. One obvious possibility is to supply rules in the form of regular expressions. Use match groups to pick out individual columns.

Comment: 1st of all - determine what the differences in those formats are and hence how different rules can be. Delphi sources and XMLs and JSONs are all text files - but very different ones.

Maybe MS Excel text fiels wizard could be enough.

Comment: With Firebird, you can declare the files as external tables and use them directly in SQL as if they existed in the database. The data type conversion to import them into "real" tables can be done with the help of built-in or custom UDFs.

Comment: @ David. Potentially the flat files can be very different. The same data can be at the beginning in one file and at the end of another, or split in two lines, or again aligned to the right on one file or to the left in another, or after a certain number of lines etc. As you can see the rules can be very complex too. Can you clarify what you mean with "regular expression" ?

Comment: @ Arioch. Unfortunately because of the wide variety of layouts the Excel text file wizard is not an option

Comment: @ Ondrej. The application will upload data in PostgreSQL and this DB has the same capability you mention (as I suppose most of the database nowdays). Problem is I want to avoid to spend a lot of time to customize each import. I was wondering if there is some documentation of somebody else who has already faced the same issue.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex
http://pcre.org/

Comment: If you input is really so rich free form that you cannot make a covering set of examples, then you'd better be ready to read about syntax parsers(and their classes) and lexers. Some starting points: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analyzer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Parsing_algorithms

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the complexity of the rules. If the only varying input is the names of the columns and the separator used, then it's pretty easy, but if you want to be able to parse completely different formats (like XML or so) as well, then it's a different story.

I myself would choose to implement a base class for a 'record' reader that reads records from a file and outputs them to a dataset or CSV.
Then, you can implement child classes that implement reading different source formats.

If you like, you can then add specific rules for those format, so you can make a generic XMLReader that descends from BaseReader, but which allows for configurable column names. But I would start with a bunch of hard-coded readers for the formats you got, until it's more clear which dialects of those formats you may encounter.

Edit: On request, an example of how it could look like.

Note, this example is far from ideal! It reads a custom format, transfers it to one specific table structure and saves that as an CSV file. You may want to split it a little further, so you can reuse the code for different table structures. Especially the field defs, you may want to be able to set in a descendant class or maybe a factory class.
But for the sake of simplicity I have taken a more rigid approach and put a little too much intelligence in one single base class.

The base class has the logic needed to create an in-memory dataset (I used a TClientDataSet). It can 'Migrate' a file. In practice, this means it reads, validates and exports the file.

The reading is abstract and must be implemented in a child class. It should read the data to the in memory dataset. That allows you to do all necessary validation in the client dataset. This allows to you enforce field types and sized and do any additional checking if you need to, in a database/file format agnostic way.

The validating and writing is done using the data in the dataset. From the moment where the source file is parsed to a dataset, no knowledge about the source file format is required anymore.

Declaration:
Don't forget to use `DB, DBClient`.

```
type
  TBaseMigrator = class
  private
    FData: TClientDataset;
  protected
    function CSVEscape(Str: string): string;
    procedure ReadFile(AFileName: string); virtual; abstract;
    procedure ValidateData;
    procedure SaveData(AFileName: string);
  public
    constructor Create; virtual;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure MigrateFile(ASourceFileName, ADestFileName: string); virtual;
  end;
```

Implementation:

```
{ TBaseReader }

constructor TBaseMigrator.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FData := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  FData.FieldDefs.Add('ID', ftString, 20, True);
  FData.FieldDefs.Add('Name', ftString, 60, True);
  FData.FieldDefs.Add('Phone', ftString, 15, False);
  // Etc
end;

function TBaseMigrator.CSVEscape(Str: string): string;
begin
  // Escape the string to a CSV-safe format;
  // Todo: Check if this is sufficient!
  Result := '"' + StringReplace(Result, '"', '""', [rfReplaceAll]) + '"';
end;

destructor TBaseMigrator.Destroy;
begin
  FData.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TBaseMigrator.MigrateFile(ASourceFileName, ADestFileName: string);
begin
  // Read the file. Descendant classes need to override this method.
  ReadFile(ASourceFileName);

  // Validation. Implemented in base class.
  ValidateData;

  // Saving/exporting. For now implemented in base class.
  SaveData(ADestFileName);
end;

procedure TBaseMigrator.SaveData(AFileName: string);
var
  Output: TFileStream;
  Writer: TStreamWriter;
  FieldIndex: Integer;
begin
  Output := TFileStream.Create(AFileName,fmCreate);
  Writer := TStreamWriter.Create(Output);
  try

    // Write the CSV headers based on the fields in the dataset
    for FieldIndex := 0 to FData.FieldCount - 1 do
    begin
      if FieldIndex > 0 then
        Writer.Write(',');
      // Column headers are escaped, but this may not be needed, since
      // they likely don't contain quotes, commas or line breaks.
      Writer.Write(CSVEscape(FData.Fields[FieldIndex].FieldName));
    end;
    Writer.WriteLine;

    // Write each row
    FData.First;
    while not FData.Eof do
    begin

      for FieldIndex := 0 to FData.FieldCount - 1 do
      begin
        if FieldIndex > 0 then
          Writer.Write(',');
        // Escape each value
        Writer.Write(CSVEscape(FData.Fields[FieldIndex].AsString));
      end;
      Writer.WriteLine;

      FData.Next
    end;

  finally
    Writer.Free;
    Output.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TBaseMigrator.ValidateData;
begin
  FData.First;
  while not FData.Eof do
  begin
    // Validate the current row of FData
    FData.Next
  end;
end;
```

An example child class: TIniFileReader, which reads inifile sections as if they were database records. As you can see, you only need to implement the logic to read the file.

```
type
  TIniFileReader = class(TBaseMigrator)
  public
    procedure ReadFile(AFileName: string); override;
  end;

{ TIniFileReader }

procedure TIniFileReader.ReadFile(AFileName: string);
var
  Source: TMemIniFile;
  IDs: TStringList;
  ID: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Initialize an in-memory dataset.
  FData.Close; // Be able to migrate multiple files with one instance.
  FData.CreateDataSet;

  // Parsing a weird custom format, where each section in an inifile is a
  // row. Section name is the key, section contains the other fields.
  Source := TMemIniFile.Create(AFileName);
  IDs := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Source.ReadSections(IDs);

    for i := 0 to IDs.Count - 1 do
    begin
      // The section name is the key/ID.
      ID := IDs[i];

      // Append a row.
      FData.Append;

      // Read the values.
      FData['ID'] := ID;
      FData['Name'] := Source.ReadString(ID, 'Name', '');
      // Names don't need to match. The field 'telephone' in this propriety
      // format maps to 'phone' in your CSV output.
      // Later, you can make this customizable (configurable) if you need to,
      // but it's unlikely that you encounter two different inifile-based
      // formats, so it's a waste to implement that until you need it.
      FData['Phone'] := Source.ReadString(ID, 'Telephone', '');

      FData.Post;
    end;

  finally
    IDs.Free;
    Source.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: OP wants to keep the variations outside of the code. By using rules which are then passed to the parser. Your proposal bakes the rules into statically compiled code. Which is somewhat less convenient.

Comment: @ Golez. Unfortunately the source can be very different and so the rules. I think I may have to parse different formats. Tell me more about the base class you mention to transform my file into CSV, then the upload of CSV into the DB is rather easy

Comment: Make each reader implementation a DLL (or runtime package) in a particular folder and have the primary data pump application load those.  It avoid recompiling the base app all the time and makes creating new readers fairly straightforward.  If the record definitions are that complex, the configuration files are going to approach a scripting language quickly enough that the OP is going to be most of the way around the configuration complexity clock in short order.

Comment: Hi Afrazier, can you tell me more about these scripting languages ? Thanks

Comment: My point is that if your file specifications are so complex that they need to involve concepts like conditionals or looping, the rules required to read them will end up looking like a snippet of code.  Well, now you either have to build what amounts to a simple script interpreter, which will probably end up not being complex enough (not to mention buggy until you get it perfected), or hunt down and figure out how to embed a scripting engine into your application (like Lua or PascalScript or WSH) and then write scripts in a scripting language...

Comment: ...which is going to be nearly as fun as writing mixed HTML/JavaScript/PHP in Notepad, and still buggy until you're comfortable with the embedding and script host interface.  Or you can just write code in native Delphi, which already has a rich language RTL, compiler, and IDE that you're already comfortable with.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You could indeed put those parsers in separate dll's, or you could do that later if you want/need to. Its just that in my experience, every case you try to address upfront will never be used, and for each format you encounter you'll have to write exceptions, which not only mess up your code and make it more complex, but indeed, you still have to alter your statically compiled code. When dealing with 'custom formats from customers', you cannot define the boundaries upfront. So therefor I suggest to at least *start* with some hard coded parsers, and maybe add config/rules later.

Comment: @piopio On request, I've added an example. Note that there's a lot to improve and you can make it quite a lot more flexible, but with that flexibility comes more work. I think you should start simple and add complexity when you need to. Maybe you need to refactor, maybe you need to rewrite the lot later. But as I can put this example together in less than half an hour, you can easily you should by then be experienced enough to refactor or rebuild the lot to your exact needs in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @piopio Example is 'as is'. It compiles, but I haven't done extensive testing. It's just to show you the structure. ;)

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help, very much appreciated !

Comment: @Afrazier, your idea of the scripting language is very interesting but it seems there is way too much "fun" for me

Comment: @Golez, your solution looks to me the most viable for my skills at the moment. I can adopt your solution and in addition to load the rules of the ReadFile and ValidateData. I will start with very simple rules moving to the more complex ones when required.

Comment: That was the point: Doing everything in code is almost certainly going to be easier and better than trying to cobble something else together. Scripting engines and domain specific languages have their place, but this probably isn't one of them.

Comment: Rules should 1) choose back-end parser implementation (this is XML-like, this is JSON-like, this is CSV-like) and do its initial simplistic setup (columns names are... columns widths are... each record starts with "bla-bla X" and ends with nearmost "foo foo X bax", etc). For more complex cases you'd better implement separate parsers.

Comment: @ Afrazier and Arioch, Thank you for your further information. This is more or less what I had in my mind (even if much less refined than that) but I was wondering if there was any quicker way.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to the problems faced by "screen scrapers".  If end users are intended to be able to use this, I would avoid regular expressions (except as an internal implementation detail, if needed) and not expose raw regular expression editing to end users.

Instead, I would let them load up samples of their data files, and construct their rules visually, with a drag, and drop style.

1. Click a "Match text" button, click and drag to select a rectangular region on the screen. Have options so that it might be allowed to move a certain amount up or down or left or right, if the format isn't precise or repeatable. Establish limits on how far you can go outside the original box.
2. Click a "grab text" button, click and drag to a rectangular or non-rectangular (flow) area on the screen.   Name the output with a field, and give it a type (integer, string[x], etc). Similar limits apply as step 1.
3. Click save and the template rules are written to disk.  Load a different file and see if the rules still apply nicely.

[Relevant wikipedia topic.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping)

Comment: Nice, but a tremendous amount of work to program, and way off limits for OP, if I judge it right.

Comment: Maybe not as much work to program in delphi as in most languages. The visual tool part would actually be pretty easy, since there are any number of visual controls that can handle most of this.